# Creating and showing vector in a reactive environtment in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I having a problem using the shiny reactive environment. My problem is that the vector is not being completed. Everytime I presss the buttom the output goes to the row bellow, but erase the previous elemnt.

This is my code:

````
---
title: "teste"
author: "Teste1"
date: "03/01/2022"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r}

actionButton("action1", "Press Button")


```


```{r, echo= FALSE, message = FALSE}

reactive({
  u <- input$action1
  
  w<- u + 2651641684
  
x <- c()
    
  x[input$action1] <- paste("Texto",format(Sys.time(), "%S"))
   
 print(x)
  }) 
```
````

Why when I `print(x)` the vector doesnt store the previous elements when I press the button?

Any help?

Comment: `x <- c()`.  You reset `x` each time the reactive is called.

Comment: Perhaps you want `observe` instead of `reactive`? The former is *greedy*, the latter *lazy*, meaning that if the output from `reactive` is never needed by something else, it will not fire. (BTW, should the `reactive` be assigned to an output?)

Comment: @Limey yes, I understand. And everytime I press the button the `x` vector is erased.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for your time. How can I use observe? In any situation I will need to avoid use `x <- c()`, right?

Comment: Try replacing `reactive(...)` with `observe(...)`. I suggest you read https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html, where *3.3.2 Laziness* references lazy reactive operators, and *3.6 Observers* the more greedy operators.

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you what you want?

````
    ---
    title: "teste"
    author: "Teste1"
    date: "03/01/2022"
    output: html_document
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ```{r}
    actionButton("action1", "Press Button")
    ```


    ```{r, echo= FALSE, message = FALSE}
    v <- reactiveValues(x=c(), u=0)

    observeEvent(input$action1, {
      v$u <- v$u + 1
      w <- v$u + 2651641684
      v$x[v$u] <- paste("Texto",format(Sys.time(), "%S"))
      print(v$x)
    }) 
    ```
````

Comment: thanks for youtr time. I think I understood the idea. Its not showing the vector in Viewer panel, only on the console panel. How can I show this in my View panel?